# How many even $4$-digit numbers can be made such that the sum of ones and tens $=4$??

Tags: combinatorics

We have the set of numbers $(0,1,...,9)$.

I try solving this and I get result $=270$.

$$\frac{9!}{8!}*\frac{10!}{9!}*3=270$$

I used the formula for variations: $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

Is this correct and is there another way of solving this?

Comment: $\frac{9!}{8!}$ is simply equal to $9$.  Similarly $\frac{10!}{9!}$ is simply equal to $10$.  Do not unnecessarily use overly complicated formulas when they are not needed.  You have nine options for the leading digit (*since it cannot be zero*).  Period.  Full stop.  We don't need to talk about $\frac{9!}{8!}$ here.

Comment: Continuing, we have $10$ options for the hundred's digit.  Now... as for the one's digit and ten's digit., you used the number $3$.  Why?  Try counting again how many options there are for one's digit and ten's digit such that they add up to $4$.  (*There are more than three... let's start listing them... 04, 13, ..., 40*).  Finish by applying multiplication principle (*rule of product*) and conclude.

Comment: As an aside, this is a question about *counting* and falls under the label of (*elementary*) (*enumerative*) combinatorics.  Although many examples in probability will use techniques learned in combinatorics in their solutions, this question as written has absolutely nothing to do with probability.  As such, probability should not have been mentioned in the title or tags or anywhere else.

Comment: There are $5$ ways I think, $04,40,13,31,22$, because the number have to be even we are left with $3$ ways.

Comment: Who ever said that it needed to be even?  I don't see the word even appearing anywhere in your post (*until your most recent edit after I wrote that*).  If you intended to be asking how many *even* 4-digit numbers can be made such that the one's digit and ten's digit add up to $4$, then you are correct.  There are $270$ ways, and your approach was correct (*but you still had no reason to refer to "the formula for variations"*)